# Making an Oracle JDK docker image

Tags: java, docker, openshift, dockerfile

I'm trying to create docker image for oracle JDK but the only image I can find is the open JDK. Our applications uses oracle JDK so it is mandatory to build oracle JDK docker images. My question is if there is any way to build customised docker images from tar files or something like that. And if I can what I will write in docker file FROM arg?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an [Atlassian blog post](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/minimal-java-docker-containers/) that describes how to build an Oracle JDK docker container.

And here is an existing [Oracle JDK image on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/alpine-java/), and [another](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8/).

Note the license disclaimers in the READMEs, though. I'm not sure that is enough to bypass the "Limitations on Redistribution" clause in the [Oracle JDK License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html). Probably safer to use their Dockerfiles and the blog as a basis to create your own. Just put it in a private repo rather than on docker hub.

For completeness, here is the Dockerfile content from the blog post:

```
# AlpineLinux with a glibc-2.21 and Oracle Java 8

FROM alpine:3.2
MAINTAINER Anastas Dancha [...]

# Install cURL
RUN apk --update add curl ca-certificates tar && \
    curl -Ls https://circle-artifacts.com/gh/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/6/artifacts/0/home/ubuntu/alpine-pkg-glibc/packages/x86_64/glibc-2.21-r2.apk > /tmp/glibc-2.21-r2.apk && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted /tmp/glibc-2.21-r2.apk

# Java Version
ENV JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR 8
ENV JAVA_VERSION_MINOR 45
ENV JAVA_VERSION_BUILD 14
ENV JAVA_PACKAGE       jdk

# Download and unarchive Java
RUN mkdir /opt && curl -jksSLH "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"\
  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-b${JAVA_VERSION_BUILD}/${JAVA_PACKAGE}-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzf - -C /opt &&\
    ln -s /opt/jdk1.${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.0_${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR} /opt/jdk &&\
    rm -rf /opt/jdk/*src.zip \
           /opt/jdk/lib/missioncontrol \
           /opt/jdk/lib/visualvm \
           /opt/jdk/lib/*javafx* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/javaws \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/desktop \
           /opt/jdk/jre/plugin \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/deploy* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/*javafx* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/*jfx* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libdecora_sse.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_*.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfxplugins.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libgstreamer-lite.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx*.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjfx*.so

# Set environment
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```